# Angular ng-grid - How to remove row after submit in Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-controller

I have a grid of task items loaded by ng-grid that when clicked load more information in a Modal window, of the user clicks Submit then the task is set to inactive in the DB and I need it removed from the Grid.

My Controller:

```
app.controller('taskController', ['$scope', 'myTasks', 'modalService',
function($scope, myTasks, modalService) {
    $scope.loading = true;

    // Init Grid
    $scope.myData = [];
    $scope.mySelections = [];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{field: 'headline', displayName: 'Headline', cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a class="selectedItems" ng-click="edit(row)">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>'},
            {field:'date_assigned', displayName:'Date'}],
        selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
        multiSelect: false,
        headerRowHeight:0,
        headerCellTemplate: '',
        hideHeaders: true,
        enableRowSelection: true
    };



    // Fetch tasks and populate grid
    $scope.tasks = myTasks.myTasks().then(function(tasks) {
        $scope.myData = tasks;
        $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' }
        $scope.loading = false;


        // Open model when row clicked
        $scope.edit = function (row, $scope) {

            var modalOptions = {
                closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
                actionButtonText: 'Update Task',
                headerText: 'View Task',
                headlineText: row.entity.headline,
                messageText: row.entity.message,
                assignedToText: row.entity.assigned_to_name,
                assignedByText: row.entity.assigned_by_name,
                dateAssignedText: row.entity.date_assigned
            };


            // Open modal with task details
            modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
                var status = $('#task_status').is(':checked');
                var message = $('#completed_message').val();
                var xsrf = $.param({id: row.entity.id, status: status, message: message});

                // Update task and reload grid
                myTasks.updateTask(xsrf).then(function(row) {

                        // Remove item from grid - NOT WORKING HERE
                        var index = this.row.rowIndex;
                        alert(index);
                        $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
                        $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);



                });
            });
        };

    });
}]);
```

UPDATED: To remove item from $scope.myData

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the item from $scope.myData instead of $scope.items as that its what you are binding the grid to.

Comment: Tried that and updated my code above but am getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'removeRow' of undefined

Comment: Why are you creating a function called removeRow? Why dont you just remove them item directly in the 'then' function of updateTask?

Comment: Good point, did that and now getting - TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowIndex' of undefined

Comment: Seems like I don't have scope from within this function.